# Syntax to insert a column into a table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

Is it possible to insert columns into a MySQL table??

I've created a table and named it "my_table" - I do not understand, why MySQL does not eats my syntax...

```
INSERT INTO "my_table"(
    "item" char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    "price" int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3000',
    "level" int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000',
    "super" char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    "play" char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
)
```

Error message:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"my_table"( "item" char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', "price" i' at line 1

So what's wrong with my syntax ?

Comment: If you want to insert *columns*, you need to consult the [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) statement.

Comment: `INSERT` adds rows, not columns

Comment: use ALTER instead: `ALTER TABLE \`tablename_here\` ADD \`new_column_name\` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ;`. Also, there is only INT, no such type as int(10), if the digits exceed, use other datatypes.

Comment: you should really be inserting the columns the same time you create the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to add columns to an already created table you must use ALTER.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD item char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html
http://www.techiecorner.com/560/mysql-how-to-add-column-to-existing-table/

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says quite clearly, [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) is for inserting rows of data, not altering the schema.

Look at [`ALTER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) instead.

And table/field names are delimited with backticks, not quotation marks.